# PHP - URL GET Variable Issues

Tags: php

I am passing a URL through a GET variable. When I echo the variable on the next page, it displays the URL without special characters. For example, take the URL:

`http://example.com/upload?url=http://www.test.com/this%20is%20the%20image.jpg`

When this code executes:

`echo $_GET['url'];`

the result is:

`http://www.test.com/this is the image.jpg`

How do I get exactly what the value of the GET variable is in the URL, and not have it converted upon retrieval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to parse `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` yourself if you want the raw values in the query string.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
echo rawurlencode($_GET['url']);
```

Comment: And what will your code output for the following path: `http://example.com/upload?url=http://test.com/somepath?somevar=someval&somevar2=someval2`?

Comment: Right! Can't do a `urlencode` for this. My solution is wrong here.

Comment: It is wrong as well as the entire approach of passing non-urlencoded values through the request string.

Answer (score 0):

Consider urlencoding the url when constructing the `upload?url=...` path instead, which will add you more flexibility with urls like `http://www.test.com/this%20is%20the%20image.jpg?with=some&additional=parameters`.

So that for your example url it will be `http://example.com/upload?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%2Fthis%2020is%2020the%2020image.jpg`.

See http://php.net/urlencode for how to urlencode the variable.

Example:

**Page with link**

```
function showLink($url) {
    return "/upload?url=".urlencode($url);
}
```

**"Upload" page**

```
echo $_GET['url']
```

That way, you'll still be able to process the link resulted from `showLink("http://test.com/somepath?somevar=someval&somevar2=someval2")` properly. Otherwise, if you won't escape it in `showLink`, you'll end up with the url like `http://example.com/upload?url=http://test.com/somepath?somevar=someval&somevar2=someval2`, and it will be quite difficult to tell whether somevar2 is the part of the request to the `example.com` or to the `test.com` (btw, `$_GET['url']` will contain `http://test.com/somepath?somevar=someval` in such a case).

Comment: This is for an API, so I would prefer links just be simply pasted to keep things simpler.

Comment: My answer is exactly about keeping things simpler. The `$_GET` variable will contain exactly the urls you want, without the need to someway parsing it from the request-string. BTW you shouldn't create the request string manually in the first place (compiling it from the array instead), but unfortunately PHP doesn't provide built-in tools for doing this unfortunately.

Comment: And, by the way, my answer gives you exactly the same result you'll get with `<form action="http://example.com/upload" method="GET"><input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://test.com/somepath?somevar=someval&somevar2=someval2"></form>`. This is just the way of storing variables in a GET request. You're instead storing the variables in some other non-standart, incomplete and incompatible way, and then wanting to get your original values after the parsing in a standart way has been done. Instead of using the standart encoding, you're inventing your own and then overcoming its drawbacks.